# OpenVPN - How do you NAT a client to another client's network

Tags: nat, openvpn

I have a openVPN server setup on a AWS instance and I would like to use it to route traffic from my home client (client1, 192.168.0.0/24) to a client(client2, 10.81.0.0/16) on a machine on a second network through the openVPN server. I want to route the connections from client1 to client2's network so that I can connect to several devices in client2's network. However I dont have control over the gateway in client2's network so I can't add a route back to the vpn.

As far as I can tell I have the openVPN configuration setup in that once client1 and client2 are connected I can access client2 from client1, the routes are also setup so that if I ping a machine on client2's network the traffic is routed through the vpn but no response happens as client2's network devices do not know how to route the vpn ips back to client2.

I am assuming that I need to setup nat masqurading at client2 but I am unsure how to properly handle this as I am not that familiar with iptables.

tried on client2:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
client-to-client
route 10.81.0.0 255.255.0.0
push "route 10.81.0.0 255.255.0.0"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
... encryption info ...
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

ccd/client2

```
iroute 10.81.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

Comment: Not a programming question, please take this to e.g. superuser.com.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone with a similar issue, I found this https://arashmilani.com/post?id=53 that helped me solve the issue.

For me I needed to add the following instead of what I tried.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eno2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eno2 -o tun+ -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eno2 -j MASQUERADE
```

tun0 is the tunnel interface from the VPN and eno2 is the interface for client2's network. 10.8.0.0/24 is the default subnet for the VPN subnet.

The forwarding was the big issue, also the masquerade is based on the ip address range of the VPN on the output interface.